# Why we can't just use "useState()" from react library rather redux, whats the benefits using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am at an intermediate level of react, have question-related to the Redux, why we can't just use the "useState()" from reactLibrary instead of the Redux in the react.it will solve the same purpose managing the state throughout the application in a simple way.What I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use redux, you can access your state data from any component or screen easily.. so your state is "global level state"

if you use a normal state "component level state", you could not easily access it from other component, if you need to get this piece of state from a child component, you should passe it as a prop to this child component for example. But that become harder when there is no clear relation between 2 components.

So if you need your state to be available in many components, it's preferable to use redux to manage your state. 
And if you need your state to be available only in one component, useState() will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a big application where you have a lot of components nested within each other. Say you have an Input component and a List component. The input component is deeply embedded in another component which is inside another one and so on.

If you want to pass information from one to the other you have to pass it through all the components between them. This makes your code very messy and unreadable.

Redux solves this problem, it adds a global state which you can access and modify from every component directly.

So if your application has a certain level of complexity, it is usually a good idea to use Redux.